# Problema com Get em jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Meu *script* funciona perfeitamente, porém tem horas que requisito a página do cadastro enviado uma seleção tipo categoria, e ela manda pra barra de endereço como se fosse `$_get`, porém está tudo via `$_post` no *serialize* do *jQuery*.

Como aparece o erro, sendo que é via *post*:
https://www.meusite.com.br/cadastro?pro=produto

Como é pra ser:
https://www.sistema.g4w.com.br/cadastro

**Código JavaScript:**

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function () { 

//sessão de form produtos
   $(function () {

        $('#formss').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'matriz/mostra_select.php',
            data: $('#formss').serialize(),
            success: function (retorno) {

            $('#prods').html(retorno);

            }
          });

        });

   });


   });
```

**HTML + PHP:**

```
<form id="formss">
    <select class="select" name="bd" style="width: 95%">
            <option value=''>Selecione a Categoria para Cadastro dos Produtos</option>
      </select>
    <option value="categoria">categoria</option>';
            <input type="submit" id="novo" />
</form>

<!-- no select vai uma busca em php, ele busca no arquivo em questão na ulr no js, e retorna pra mim,
porem tem horas que ele mostra como se tivesse ido via get
codigo php abaixo, o arquivo que recebe-->

<div class="main_produtos">

<?php
    include('conecta.php');


$fila = $_POST['bd'];
$pega = $fila.'_lista';

$mostrando = "SELECT * FROM $fila order by cod desc limit 1";
$mm = mysqli_query ($con, $mostrando)  or die(mysql_error());


    $venda = mysqli_fetch_array($mm);

    $cods = $venda['cod'];

    if(empty($cods)){

        $cods = '1';

        ?>
    <?php   
    }
    else{

        $cods = $venda['cod'] + 1;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sem ver o código fica difícil de dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: E esse `option` fora do `select`?

Comment: foi um erro de edição aqui mesmo..rs, no script esta correto

Comment: amigo, a propriedade que define se é POST no $.ajax nao é a method? Tente trocar a type por method

Comment: @AdemilsonSantanadaSilva não é, troquei e esporadicamente continua o erro

Comment: Experimenta setar o method="post" na sua tag form no html. Agora entendendo melhor, o endereço que ele está disparando a url é diferente do endereço que deveria ser? Porque a referência vai ser a URL que está no momento em que você envia, então varia do endereço que você está acessando.

Comment: @JuarezTurrini nao quero que ele direciona pra outra pagina, mas me de uma resposta na mesma, mesmo sendo outra pagina

Comment: "_porém tem horas_"... estranho isso. Na área da programação essa afirmação não combina. Ou é ou não é. Seu código tb tem muitas incoerências. Poderia ao menos editar a pergunta e colocar exatamente o código correto.

Comment: o codigo esta correto, digo "tem horas" pq ele faz a requisão tranquilo, porem ele da esse bug que nao consigo resolver

Comment: Coloca o method="post" na tag <form>

Comment: Gozado que em nenhuma parte do código há o parâmetro `pro`nem tampouco o valor `produto`

Comment: Como já foi dito tem muitas inconsistências no código que colocou, desde etiquetas fora do sitio, `'` que estão a mais, etc ... Por isso sugiro que coloque o código aqui na pergunta **exatamente igual ao que tem** caso contrário não vai obter a ajuda que procura. É dificil ajudar quando o código que vemos é tudo hipotetico e não joga com o que tem que está "correto"

Comment: É verdade @Isac, não basta o problema em si, soma-se a ele o desleixo na hora de postar o código corretamente.

Comment: Amigo, não é possível reproduzir o problema com as informações que você postou, então vou dar dois chutes. Antes de mais nada, coloque no ajax ' method: "POST" ', conforme está na documentação oficial do jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Então os chutes: primeiro, no seu html, não tem "action" no form, que por padrão é get.  Então se o seu javascipt falhar, por um erro não tratado por exemplo, o e.preventDefault() nunca será acionado, e o envio será pelo form html. Quando falhar, veja no seu console alguma mensagem de erro. Segundo chute, o seu script js não está carregando do cache?

Comment: Se estiver carregando do cache, concatene algo no nome do arquivo.

Exemplo: <script src="app.js?v=2"></script>

Comment: @PauloSakamoto coloca a resposta que vou positivar, ele não deu a resposta json, mas sumiu o get da barra

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Primeiramente, altere a opção do ajax, de "type: 'post'" para "method: 'POST'", conforme está na documentação oficial do [jQuery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'matriz/mostra_select.php',
    data: $('#formss').serialize(),
    success: function (retorno) {
        $('#prods').html(retorno);
    }
});
```

Quanto ao erro em si, não é possível reproduzi-lo, mas um provável motivo é um erro de execução do javascript, que pode estar interrompendo a execução do mesmo, e neste caso, o `e.preventDefault()` nunca será ativado e o formulário será enviado pelo form do html (método GET por padrão). Quando se deparar com o erro, veja console do navegador (no Chrome apertando F12) e veja se tem algum erro de javascript.

Outro possível motivo é que em determinadas páginas o script pode estar sendo carregado do cache. Neste caso concatene algo no nome do arquivo. Exemplo:

```
<script src="app.js?v=2"></script>
<form id="#formss" method="post"></form:
```

Espero que ajude.